# ERROR 1064 (42000):right syntax to use near ')' at line 10

Tags: php, mysql, macos

So I'm trying to create a database using MYSQL and it doesn't seem to be adding the tables to mysql on Terminal, the following error codes show:

```
**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 10
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 9
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(2),
PRIMARY KEY (guest_id),
FOREIGN KEY (res_nr)
)' at line 10
ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+---------------------------------+
| Tables_in_xxxxxx_coursework_1 |
+---------------------------------+
| Reservations                    |
| Room                            |
+---------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)**
```

But this code was working earlier because when I type "SHOW TABLES;" it shows the first two tables **Room and Reservations** so the fault can't be in the first two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Room (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    room_id INT (3),
    room_type VARCHAR (15),
    guest_id INT (8),
    res_nr INT (6),
    price DECIMAL (6,2) unsigned,
    extras_id INT (2),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Reservations (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    res_no INT (6),
    guest_id INT (8),
    hotel_branch INT (5),
    room_genre VARCHAR (12),
    extras_id INT (2),
    room_id int (3),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (room_id)
    REFERENCES Room (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Employees (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    employee_id INT (6),
    ni_id INT (9),
    first_name VARCHAR (25),
    surname VARCHAR (25),
    address VARCHAR (100),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (first_name)
);

CREATE TABLE Hotel (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    hotel_branch INT (5),
    employee_id INT (6),
    hotel_name CHAR (20),
    town VARCHAR(20),
    num_rooms INT (3),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
);

CREATE TABLE Guest (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    guest_id INT (8),
    res_nr INT(6),
    first_name CHAR (25),
    surname CHAR (25),
    phone_no INT(12),
    email VARCHAR (25),
    room_id INT(3),
    extras_id(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (guest_id)
    FOREIGN KEY (res_nr)
);

CREATE TABLE Bill (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    invoice_id INT (9),
    guest_id INT (8),
    room_charge DECIMAL (8,2) unsigned,
    extra_charge DECIMAL (6,2) unsigned,
    PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (guest_id)
    REFERENCES Guest (id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are construction wrong table structure

```
        CREATE TABLE Room (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        room_id INT (3),
        room_type VARCHAR (15),
        guest_id INT (8),
        res_nr INT (6),
        price DECIMAL (6,2) unsigned,
        extras_id INT (2),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
        );

        CREATE TABLE Guest ( 
        guest_id INT (8),
         res_nr INT(6), 
         first_name CHAR (25),
         surname CHAR (25), 
         phone_no INT(12),
         email VARCHAR (25),
         room_id INT(3), 
         extras_id int (2), 
         PRIMARY KEY (guest_id), 
         CONSTRAINT fk_res FOREIGN KEY (res_nr) REFERENCES Room (id) )
```

As you can check above I have created FK res_nr using id of room as its an primary key of room table. What you were trying to do is referencing an integer value which will not work. 
Try to learn more about Fk.[ http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp ]